# Как сделать, чтоб Бот отправлял сообщения через 10 секунд

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

как сделать чтобы бот писал сообщения каждый раз после 10 секунд?
Дискорд Бот на питоне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не написали какой текст и как будет бот реагировать. Я использовал асинхронный бесконечный цикл, также вы можете сделать это с помощью цикла for. После чего, я ввожу асинхронную команду sleep и количество секунд в скобках.

```
import asyncio
@bot.event
async def on_message(mes):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        await mes.send('Hello World!')
```